# Unable to find output file in ubuntu generated by python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, spyder

I am currently working on python 3.6 using spider. I have written a code which in theory works in windows but it does not on ubuntu 18.04. My problem is that I want to write my results on a text file but it is nowhere to be found.

I write the following:

```
with open('Vx1.txt', 'w+') as fv1:
    for itemv1 in var:
        fv1.write("%s\n" % itemv1)
fv1.close()
```

But I am unable to find the output file Vx1.txt if there is one at all. I have tried to search from files as if I were working on a windows device and when it has not worked out I have used the console comand:

```
/$ find ~/ -type f -name "Vx1"
```

The computer does not return anything at all, just goes back to the prompt. 
Can someone please tell me how can I find my output?

Please note that I have tried with `single` and `double` commas over the words when searching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for your working directory in your IDE.

Comment: when you use `with` to open a file, there is no need for `close()` as `with` handles it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be indentation issues?

```
with open('Vx1.txt', 'w+') as fv1:
    for itemv1 in var:
         fv1.write("%s\n" % itemv1)
```